# The upgrade process from 16.04 to 18.04 doesn't start

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

When I try to upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (using `do-release-upgrade`) the upgrade process does not start. I get the following output:

> ```
> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
> Get:2 Upgrade tool [1'260 kB]                                                  
> Fetched 1'261 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
> authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
> extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'
>
> Reading cache
>
> Checking package manager
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree        
> Reading state information... Done
> Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                          
> Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
> Reading package lists... Done    
> Building dependency tree          
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Restoring original system state
>
> Aborting
> Reading package lists... Done    
> Building dependency tree          
> Reading state information... Done
> ```

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It requires internet connection.

Comment: I do have internet connection.